# Using tf.gather_nd() to select elements of a tensor

Tags: python-3.x, indexing, tensorflow

I have 2 tensors:

- A of shape [146, 33, 559]
- B of shape [146, 33]

B contains integers between 0 and 559, which serve as indeces.

What I'm after is a tensor C of shape [146, 33] where each element corresponds to the index given by B.

I tried `tf.gather_nd(A, B)` which gives me the error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): index innermost dimension length must be <= params rank; saw: 33 vs. 3
 [[Node: GatherNd = GatherNd[Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_34, _recv_contexts_1_0)]]
```

I also tried `tf.gather(A, B)` which gives me the error

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): indices[1,0] = 282 is not in [0, 146)
 [[Node: Gather = Gather[Tindices=DT_INT64, Tparams=DT_FLOAT, validate_indices=true, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Reshape_34, _recv_contexts_1_0)]]
```

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I got a working version now. I construct an array containing 146x33=4818 triplets [0,0,index_a], [0,1,index_b], ..., [146, 33, index_zz]. Then I turn that into a tf tensor and use tf.gather_nd(A, tensor). Seems like a fairly complicated way of doing it.. does this sound correct?

Comment: When we think about the 3rd dimension as channels, what you want to do is to extract exactly one channel for every element in the 146x33 "image", right? Then your solution seems correct to me. I also found using `tf.gather_nd` a bit complicated to use at first, but when you think about what the function is intended for (selecting arbitrary, non-consecutive elements) it starts to make sense :)